# What type of instance of EC2 is needed to deploy Talend Enterprise Edition in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, talend

I need to know what is type of ec2 instance minimum needed to deploy Talend ? And what instance will be best to use. Please note I am talking about Talend Enterprise Edition 5.6.1.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for asking programming questions. You would be better moving your question to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

Lets put a generic requirement to just talend installed and test would be :

Processor: 8 core
Memory : 8GB
Disk space : 20+gb to start with and preferred to have 100GB

I will link you the talend cloud pre-requisites as below,

https://help.talend.com/reader/vfK0vMfgfqfNpuDhC5QOiA/_1MIHHezdrq3wDb2NYKkXw

You can use this as a baseline to determine the instance you need and what type of processor and how much you are willing to spend on this.